# Why wordpress cannot write to directory and how to fix it?

Tags: ftp

I got message

To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed.

The solution is here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-i-can-t-install-a-new-plugin-on-my-wordpress

However, I don't quite understand about ownership.

Who owns the file?

[image]

The owners of the file is 1001?

Who the hell is 1001?

Comment: I would set the ownership to the user that your web server runs as ( Apache/Nginx ), e.g. on some servers, it's `www-data`, but what will work for you is going to be specific to your server and how you set it up

Comment: How to know who the owner should be?

Comment: As I said, that's entirely dependent on how you set up your server. You want an owner that the PHP/Apache/Nginx process can write with, that's a non-WP question though that would be better on serverfault. In all likelihood the answer is in the original tutorial on setting up your server, or ping your hosting provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fix this issue:** Set WordPress directory and file permissions to allow your webserver's user account execute+read+write access. (Typically this means setting permissions 0775 for directories and 0664 for files.)

> However, I don't quite understand about ownership.

I'd recommend a review of [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions) at Linux.com - it never hurts to know what's going on at the system level.

> The owners of the file is 1001?
>
> Who the hell is 1001?

1001 is the first "userland" user created on the system (system-level users typically have ID's in the 0-1000 range).

In this case, the user entry may be missing from `/etc/passwd` or Filezilla doesn't have read access to `/etc/passwd` to display the username associated with UID 1001.

Ensure that `/etc/passwd` has 0644 permissions (owner read+write, group and global read) and an entry for 1001 exists *or* contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: What exactly I should write in SSH

Comment: `find /path/to/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` then `find /path/to/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` then figure out which user your webserver runs under and run `chown -R x:x /path/to/wordpress` where "x:x" is your UID and the GID of the webserver user.

Comment: Thanks. How do I find out which user or webserver runs under? Who own the webserver

Comment: Run `ps aux | grep -E "apache|nginx"` and take note of the USER column (far left) to get the username associated with the webserver service (if you're running something other than Apache or nginx, change the `grep` expression accordingly).